# Timezone for Shopify API order query parameters

Tags: shopify

The [Shopify order API](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) allows the specification of date-based query parameters (e.g. `created_at_min`). I was wondering what timezone is expected for those dates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't provide a timezone Shopify will assume UTC. To make life easier, you can specify a timezone in the request, e.g. `2008-01-10T11:00:00-05:00`

N.B: Make sure you URL encode the timestamp before you pass it, otherwise you'll run into issues with some characters (`+` in particular).

Comment: For anyone who runs across this, It looks like Shopify now defaults to the store's timezone if none is passed. Even more reason to specify the timezone with your request.