# Shopify created_at_min parameter with event endpoint does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shopify, shopify-api

I am attempting to get a list of orders from the event endpoint using Google Apps Script.

The server either ignores the `created_at_min parameter`, or returns a `500 error`.

I have found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719047/timezone-for-shopify-api-order-query-parameters), and attempted to encode my timestamp as it suggests (please see below for what I have done), but unfortunately have been unsuccessful.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
options = {
'headers': {
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${key}:${pass}`),
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
},
method: 'GET'
}

// attempt 0 to verify I can successfully get data from the endpoint
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?filter=order", options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 0');
    Logger.log(e)
}

// attempt 1
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min=2022-04-25T16:15:47-04:00", options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 1');
    Logger.log(e)
}
// attempt 2
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min=2022-04-25T16:15:47%2B04:00", options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 2');
    Logger.log(e)
}
// attempt 3
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min=2022-04-25", options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 3');
    Logger.log(e)
}
// attempt 4
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min="+Utilities.base64encode("2022-04-25T16:15:47-04:00"), options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 4');
    Logger.log(e)
}
// attempt 5
try {
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<storeUrl>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min="+Utilities.base64encode("2022-04-25"), options)); }
catch (e) {
    Logger.log('attempt 5');
    Logger.log(e)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved this issue.

The problem was the amount of data the server was attempting to return was too large, so it was returning a 500 error.

Modifying the fetch URL to include `created_at_max` solved the issue!

`UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://lily-and-fox-usa.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/events.json?created_at_min=2022-04-25T16:15:47%2B04:00&created_at_max=2022-04-26T16:15:47%2B04:00", options)`